# Showing centralizer of element in $S_6$ is not abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

> Q: Explain why there are $18$ elements of $S_6$ which commute with $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3) (4\ 5\ 6)$ and why the centralizer $C (\sigma)$ is not abelian.

I got the first part fine, I think. I basically reasoned that elements that commute are the same elements that are in the centralizer. In that case, the question is how many elements are in the conjugacy class. $(1\ 2\ 3)$, $(2\ 3\ 1)$, $(3\ 1\ 2)$ all represent the same cycle, as do $(4\ 5\ 6)$, $(5\ 6\ 4)$, and $(6\ 4\ 5)$. So the number of elements with the $(1\ 2\ 3)/(2\ 3\ 1)/(3\ 1\ 2)$ first and the $(4\ 5\ 6)/(5\ 6\ 4)/(6\ 4\ 5)$ second is $3\times3 = 9$. Multiply this by $2$ to get the options where the order is reversed, and you get $18$.

For the second part, I know I could just pick two elements of the centralizer and explicitly show it is not abelian, although I feel like that is not what the question-setter is looking for. It seems I'm forgetting some fact about abelian subgroups or the symmetric group. Can anyone point out what it is I'm missing?

Comment: I am a bit worried whether your reasoning is correct when you write "...to get the options where the order is reversed". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: The *index* of the centralizer equals the size of the conjugacy class.

Comment: But, yes, I think you're just meant to find two elements that commute with $\sigma$ but not with each other.

Comment: What I meant is, if gσ = σg, then σ = gσg^-1. Given the act of conjugation permutes the numbers in the cycle, there are 18 different permutations that will still leave you with the same result as (123)(456), and each is associated with a g.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can easily solve part two by making just a little bit explicit your solution of part one.

You have seen that in the centralizer of $\sigma$ there are elements (which actually generate it)
$$
\sigma_{1} = ( 1 2 3 ), \sigma_{2} = (4 5 6), \tau = (1 4) (2 5) (3 6),
$$
where $\tau$ conjugates $\sigma_{1}$ to $\sigma_{2}$, and thus centralizes their product $\sigma$.

But then you have shown that $\sigma_{1}$ and $\tau$ do not commute.